# Obj-C to Swift Coredata conversion

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data

Ok, just starting to look at Swift and trying to use a `Coredata` model and `SQLfile` from an existing Obj-C program.

- Created new swift Coredata project
- replaced the coredata model with the existing model
- pointed program to sql data file
- Created Swift `NSMangagedObject` Subclass

Run program, get an error that class types don't match.

- Remove Swift `NSMangedObject` Subclass and created Objective-C version

Run program, no issues, fetch executes nicely.

I want to eventually rewrite the program in swift, but I'll have to deal with old SQL data files. Is there a way to get this to work without having to blend the two languages?

I have not tried this, but is this something lightweight migration would do?

-[EDIT]---

Error message is in console:

"fatal error: NSAarry element failed to match the Swift Array Element type"

fetch Code:

```
 let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Account")
 var error:NSError?=nil
 var fetchResults = managedObjectContext?executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)! as [Account]

 for aAccount in fetchResults {
 println(aAccount.name)
 }
```

This code does works - IF the NSManagedObject Subclass (Account) IS Obj-C

This code does NOT work - IF the NSManagedObject subclass (Account) IS Swift  - This is when I get the error.

The NSManagedObject Subclass is generated through "Create NSMangedObject Subclass" in XCode.

The CoreData Model and the SQL data file are from a previous, functioning, program when 100% Obj-C.

-[EDIT 2]-------

Unless I did something wrong, it is type cased...

```
 var fetchResults = ...(request, error: &error)! as [Account]
```

To test, I changed the above to:

```
 var fetchResults = ...(request, error: &error)! as [NSManagedObject]
```

with this change the following works - as you would expect:

```
 for aAccount in fetchResults {

        println(aAccount.valueForKey("name")!)     
 }
```

The following DOES NOT work (added it inside the for-in loop):

```
 if let account = aAccount as? Account {
            println(account.name)
 }
```

So, it will NOT let me cast to the Swift Account Class. I used Xcode's "Create ManagedObject Subclass" to create the Swift subclass.

-[EDIT 3]-----

XCode Version: 6.1

Account.swift file:

```
 import Foundation
 import Coredata

 class Account: NSManagedObject {

 @NSManaged var name: String
 @NSManaged var number: String
 @NSManaged var type: String
 @NSManaged var status: String

 }
```

If I create an Obj-C version of Account (Account.h and Account.m), add them to the Bridging-Header, remove the .swift version, everything works.

Comment: Please give more info. Code. Compiler Error Messages. etc...

Comment: What I immediately noticed is that your class name is `Accout` but your entity name is `Account` (note the missing 'n')

Comment: typo when putting it into SO, was on two different computers, so I couldn't cut-n-paste - Spelling is correct in program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `NSManagedObject` in `fetchedResults` to your Swift class in order to access the properties of the Swift class directly.

```
for aAccount in fetchResults {
 println(aAccount.name)   // NOT GOING TO WORK
 }
```

`aAccount` will be a `NSManagedObject` so you must cast this to your Swift class in order to access it's property via the Swift class (`aAccount.name`).  Otherwise you have to access the property like this

```
aAccount.getValueForKey("Name")
```

Alternately try this

```
for managedObject in fetchResults {
 if let account = managedObject as? Account {
     println(account.name)   
  }
 }
```

Here is one of my Swift model classes, try adding the `@objc()`

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(AssetX)
class AssetX: BaseNode {

    @NSManaged var childCostTotal: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var dateOfManufacture: NSDate
    @NSManaged var dateOfPurchase: NSDate
    @NSManaged var dateOfValuation: NSDate
    @NSManaged var invoice: NSAttributedString
    @NSManaged var make: String
    @NSManaged var model: String
    @NSManaged var photo: NSAttributedString
    @NSManaged var purchaseCost: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var serialNo: String
    @NSManaged var valuationCost: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var category: AssetCategory
}
```

The base class is:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(BaseNode)
class BaseNode: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var canCollapse: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var canExpand: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var details: NSAttributedString
    @NSManaged var displayName: String
    @NSManaged var isExpanded: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var isLeaf: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var isSelectable: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var isSpecialGroup: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var reminderDate: NSDate
    @NSManaged var reminderPeriod: String
    @NSManaged var sortIndex: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var status: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var children: NSSet
    @NSManaged var linkedTo: People
    @NSManaged var parent: BaseNode

    var found:Bool = false

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, see addition edit. It will NOT type cast to the Swift version of the class.

Comment: Post the code for the generated Swift Account class, maybe an XCode bug

Comment: And apologies, I did'nt see that you were in fact already casting to Account in your code.